# Show activity indicator while searching

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I'm working on an app that searches for photos online. When I press the search button here is what I'm doing:

```
- (IBAction)searchPhotos:(id)sender
{
    if (internetReachable.isConnected) {
        _searchingView.hidden = FALSE;
        NSLog(@"Yoooouuuuu... You've got what I need!");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [dataHandler searchPublicFlickrPhotosByKeyword:_tfKeyword.text];
        });
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToPhotos" sender:self];
    } else {
        _alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Connection" message:@"There seems to be a problem with your internet connection. Please check your connection and try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [_alert show];
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the uiview: _searchingView will not show. Any ideas? The conditional statement is definitely true because the NSLog comes up.

Comment: maybe you'd want to perform segue after search completes? It's hard to say without seeing the segue code. And why are you performing network operation on the main thread (despite it being async)?

Comment: Kambala, would you mind to show me how the network operation should be performed? Should it be on global thread? And yes I do want to perform the segue after the search. How do I do this?

Comment: Is the property `searchingView` properly connected?

Answer (score 0):

After dinking with it some more I found that the queue should have been set up as follows:

```
if (internetReachable.isConnected) {
    _searchingView.hidden = FALSE;
    NSLog(@"Yoooouuuuu... You've got what I need!");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        [dataHandler searchPublicFlickrPhotosByKeyword:_tfKeyword.text];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToPhotos" sender:self];
        });
    });
}
```